# Total variation versus absolute continuity

Tags: measure-theory

Can you given an example of a family of measures $\{\mu_t\}$, with $t\in T$, $T$ a topological space, that are continuous in $t$ with respect to the total variation norm but not absolutely continuous with respect to any $\sigma$-additive finite measure? Is there an example when $T$ is compact or Lindelof?

Comment: You're probably going to want to add some conditions on this statement. Right now, the answer is trivially no since every measure on a given measurable space is absolutely continuous with respect to the measure that gives every non-empty set measure $\infty$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was thinking of a $\sigma$-additive finite measure.

Comment: In general, editing a question to add conditions that invalidate an answer already posted is bad practice on this site.

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be an uncountable space equipped with the discrete topology. In particular, for any topological space $Y$, every function $f:T \to Y$ is continuous.

Hence, we are free to choose any family of measures $\{\mu_t\}$ on $(T, B(T))$  and $t \mapsto \mu_t$ will be continuous for the total variation norm. In particular, we can take $\mu_t = \delta_t$ so that $\mu_t(A) = 1_{t \in A}$.

Now suppose that $\mu$ is a measure such that $\mu_t$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ for every $t$ then $\mu$ must assign positive measure to every non-empty Borel subset of $T$. Since $T$ has the discrete topology, this means that $\mu(\{t\}) > 0$ for every $t \in T$ and hence that $\mu(T) = \infty$.

Comment: This works. Is there an example in which $T$ is a compact space?

Comment: I am precisely thinking of cases in which the family of measures that you propose is not continuous with respect to the total variation norm.

Comment: I don't have time to think more about this right now and don't have an example straight away. In future, it'd probably be helpful for you understanding these things if you try to think about these edge cases and work out what conditions you want to impose and include them in the question so that you don't get answers like mine.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. I voted it up. I am wondering if there is also an answer with a compact space. I’ll edit the question to clarify.